# NW.js Local Storage Cache Still Persists Even After App Uninstallation

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, local-storage, node-webkit

In my NW.js app, I store some data in the Local Storage. Now I want to delete the app and surely the Local Storage data as well. I move the app to the trash and clean it up. Also, I delete cache information related to the app located in `/Users/<username>/Library/Caches/<yourmagicapp>`.

But unfortunately, all this doesn't help. After building a new copy of the app and shipping it to the macOS Application folder the Local Storage data restores from somewhere like it never has been deleted at all. All the data still here.

The question is how to delete all the stored data and where does it sit? Or at least from where to read about it because I couldn't find information in the nw.js official docs. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the location of the local app data on any OS by doing `console.log(nw.App.dataPath);`. This folder is created automatically by Chromium and exists separately from your app in a user account specific location. When you delete the app, this folder remains because it may contain settings, in case you reinstall it or replace it with a newer version of the app.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This will save me time to find out the path on Windows as well. I found the app name folder in the Caches folder but not sure what it contains. Does it contain something valuable?

Comment: It likely contains a bunch of junk files that don't matter that chromium cares about and will recreate every time your app is launched if those files are removed. May also contain some user specific stuff like remembering username/passwords, or browser local storage, etc. I use this folder as a place to store temp files, or user settings. `path.join(nw.App.dataPath, 'settings.json')`.

Answer (score 1):

In **macOS** to reset your **NW.js** app **Local Storage** manually you need to delete the next folder:

```
/Users/<userName>/Library/ApplicationSupport/<yourAppName>/Default/Local Storage
```

After deleting this folder your NW.js app local storage will be reset.

In the **Default folder**, you can also find **Session Storage** and **IndexedDB** folders as well, in case you need to reset different data.

To remove all the data of your app you can also delete a folder located here:

```
/Users/<userName>/Library/Caches/<yourAppName>
```